# Figuring out the correct way to connect a duct fan (europe)

Tags: electrical

I found a new old duct fan in a garage sale, the seller said he bought it around 10 years ago, never used it. Anyways, it was in pristine condition inside its plastic wrap but came without a box and with a tiny instruction leaflet, the only markings I found as to what it is is just stylized "CATA" written on the leaflet.

Anyways, on the backside its got 3 electrical connector marked N, L and SL. The leaflet explains(in german) that blue wire -> N, brown wire -> L and black wire -> SL.

So that's what's confusing me. There is no black wire here and while N would probably be neutral, I have no clue as to what the L or SL are. I think the L should be the hot wire (being brown) but I can't be sure.

Anybody got any insight into this?

EDIT:

I found this diagram while looking for "CATA" duct fans, it also has the N L and SL markings and I think sticking the blue wire in N and brown into both L and SL should make it work?

Still strange though, if they wanted the hot wire in SL for a switch, why also have it also permanently connected to the L? Might have something to do with the "TIMER" potentiometer on its backside..

[image]

Comment: L = line, SL = switched line. For the rest you should probably post a photo.

Comment: Yeah, it may be that the fan can be configured to run for a number of minutes after the light is turned off. It's probably a bathroom fan.

Comment: Right on! I decided to just try it and connecting L with SL made it go, after disconnecting SL the timer potentiometer controls how long it goes I think

Comment: @Fizz yu might as well make that an answer, the posted schematic says precisely that.   SL switches the lamp and also runs a rundown tm

Comment: [pardon the interruption](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63644/pressing-enter-in-comment-box-unexpectedly-submits-form)... SL also runs a rundown timer for the fan which is why L must be always connected.

Comment: This question is unclear. You say "there is no black wire here", what/where is "here"? Do you mean "there is a blue wire going from the circuit board to the N of the connector block, and brown to L, but no black or other wire going to the SL"? Or do you mean "mains wiring in {my country} doesn't have any black wires"? I assume the latter? In which case, is your question "how do I make a switched live versus a live?" or "I know how to make a switched live versus a live, but does the code in {my country} require me to use a black wire or can I use brown for both?"

Answer (score 1):

L = line, SL = switched line. It may be that the fan can be configured to run for a number of minutes after the light is turned off. It's probably a bathroom fan.